# Adding variables to json parsing function to carry over to other function in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, python-3.x

Looking to parse some json and move variables created from some of the json values over to another function. Can't seem to get both to work together.

```
def payload(nid):
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    with urlopen("www.site1.com/" + nid + ".json") as rr:
        result = json.loads(rr.read().decode(rr.headers.get_content_charset("utf-8")))
    title = (result["title"])
    body = (result["body"]["und"])
```

I try to use variables created from above "title" and "body" to create a new json payload, posting it to another website.

```
def add(nid,title,body):
    url = "www.site2.com/stuff.json"
    headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
    payload = {
        "auth_token": auth_token,
        "document":
            {
                "external_id": nid,
                "fields": [
                    {"name": "title", "value": title, "type": "string"},
                    {"name": "path", "value": "https://" + env + ".website" + language + "/node/" + nid,
                     "type": "enum"},
                    {"name": "nid", "value": nid, "type": "integer"},
                    {"name": "body", "value": body, "type": "text"},
                ]}
    }

    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    print("{} was added".format(nid))
```

I am unsure how to move nid, title, body from one function to the next.

Sorry in advance, day 3 of python. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean how to pass these variables to the add function?

Comment: call it as `add(nid, title=title, body=body)` from your `payload()` function

Comment: if you have to call it seprately, then write an return statement at the end of payload() functionlike this. `return (title,body)`. Then wherever you are calling the `add()` function, you already have `nid` with you, correct? So, call the `add()` function as described above. for example: `result = payload(nid)`. Then `result[0]` will contain `title` and `result[1]` will contain `body`. pass it to the `add` function as `add(nid, title=result[0], body=result[1])`

Comment: Yeah, I was able to return title and body. So that worked out. Thanks for steering me in the right direction. Now to debug why the post is not working :)